# Not being able to get the correct result

Tags: c#, linq

I believe i'm missing something simple here, but i just can't figure it out. Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

**The problem**:
The results that end up in the `resultsWithMedia` array only contain results that were matched against the first item in `mediaTypesList`. I've tried using `Exists()`, `Find()` and `Contains()`, but with no luck. I get the same kind of behavior each time.

**For example**: if `mediaTypesList` contains `{"video", "link", "photo"}` values, the `resultsWithMedia` will only hold results that are of type `video`.

What i'm trying to achieve is to have `resultsWithMedia` hold the values who's `type` matches any of the values in `mediaTypesList`.

**The code**:

```
 public void GetPostsWithMedia(string from, string before, string mediaTypes)
    {
        // ... some variable declarations

        List<string> mediaTypesList = new List<string>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mediaTypes))
        {
            var list = mediaTypes.Split(',');

            foreach (var type in list)
            {
                mediaTypesList.Add(type);
            }
        }

        // ... some more code 

        // Note: r.Data is a Dictionary that contains strings as it's values
        var resultsWithMedia = (from r in response.Results
                                where r.Data.ContainsKey("Type") && mediaTypesList.Exists(t => t == r.Data["Type"]) 
                                select new 
                                {
                                    // ... different variables
                                }).ToArray();

        }
    }
```

Comment: `Contains()` should work for you, what results are you getting with it?

Comment: I was getting only results that match the first element in the list, instead of any element in the list. Using `Trim()` and `ToLower()` solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get results with media in one query:

```
var query = from r in response.Results.Where(x => x.Data.ContainsKey("Type"))
            join m in mediaTypes.Split(',')
                 on r.Data["Type"] equals m
            select new {
                ...
            };
```

If you need case-insensitive comparison for media type and data, apply ToLower(): `on r.Data["Type"].ToLower() equals m.ToLower()`. Also consider to apply `m.Trim()` if there is empty space in media type name after splitting string (as Euphoric suggested).

Comment: Thanks! using `Trim()` and `ToLower()` did the trick. I knew i was missing something trivial.

Answer (score 1):

I've rewritted your code a bit.

```
var mediaTypesList = mediaTypes.Split(',').Select(e => e.Trim()).ToList();

var resultsWithMedia = response.Results.Data.Where(e => e.ContainsKey("Type") && mediaTypesList.Contains(e["Type"]))
            .Select(a => new {
                              // ... different variables
                              }).ToArray();
```

It looks simpler for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check spaces in `mediaTypes` before and after `,`

Preferably change

```
mediaTypesList.Add(type.Trim());
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly you want to match by first element.
[Enumerable.First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050.aspx) will do the trick:

```
   var resultsWithMedia = (from r in response.Results
                            where r.Data.ContainsKey("Type") && 
                            mediaTypesList.First(t => t == r.Data["Type"]) 
                            select new 
                            {
                                // ... different variables
                            }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem was that i was only getting results that match the first element, instead of results that match any of the elements in the list.